# Manim Zoom Not Preserving Line Thickness?

Tags: manim

Here is a modified version of some example code, which is from the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/ed6aae68877fceacc0aa747af018cbee57715e79/English/extra/faqs/faqs.md#zoomed-scene-example). The  only change is that I've added a line:

```
from manimlib.imports import *

class ZoomedSceneExample(ZoomedScene):
    CONFIG = {
        "zoom_factor": 0.3,
        "zoomed_display_height": 1,
        "zoomed_display_width": 6,
        "image_frame_stroke_width": 20,
        "zoomed_camera_config": {
            "default_frame_stroke_width": 3,
        },
    }

    def construct(self):
        # Set objects
        dot = Dot().shift(UL*2)
        a_line = Line((0,0,0),(1,1,0)).shift(UL*2) ## THIS IS THE ONLY CHANGE
        self.add(a_line)                           ## TO THE EXAMPLE CODE

        image=ImageMobject(np.uint8([[ 0, 100,30 , 200],
                                     [255,0,5 , 33]]))
        image.set_height(7)
        frame_text=TextMobject("Frame",color=PURPLE).scale(1.4)
        zoomed_camera_text=TextMobject("Zommed camera",color=RED).scale(1.4)

        self.add(image,dot)

        # Set camera
        zoomed_camera = self.zoomed_camera
        zoomed_display = self.zoomed_display
        frame = zoomed_camera.frame
        zoomed_display_frame = zoomed_display.display_frame

        frame.move_to(dot)
        frame.set_color(PURPLE)

        zoomed_display_frame.set_color(RED)
        zoomed_display.shift(DOWN)

        # brackground zoomed_display
        zd_rect = BackgroundRectangle(
            zoomed_display,
            fill_opacity=0,
            buff=MED_SMALL_BUFF,
        )

        self.add_foreground_mobject(zd_rect)

        # animation of unfold camera
        unfold_camera = UpdateFromFunc(
            zd_rect,
            lambda rect: rect.replace(zoomed_display)
        )

        frame_text.next_to(frame,DOWN)

        self.play(
            ShowCreation(frame),
            FadeInFromDown(frame_text)
        )

        # Activate zooming
        self.activate_zooming()

        self.play(
            # You have to add this line
            self.get_zoomed_display_pop_out_animation(),
            unfold_camera
        )

        zoomed_camera_text.next_to(zoomed_display_frame,DOWN)
        self.play(FadeInFromDown(zoomed_camera_text))

        # Scale in     x   y  z
        scale_factor=[0.5,1.5,0]

        # Resize the frame and zoomed camera
        self.play(
            frame.scale,                scale_factor,
            zoomed_display.scale,       scale_factor,
            FadeOut(zoomed_camera_text),
            FadeOut(frame_text)
        )

        # Resize the frame
        self.play(
            frame.scale,3,
            frame.shift,2.5*DOWN
        )

        # Resize zoomed camera
        self.play(
            ScaleInPlace(zoomed_display,2)
        )


        self.wait()

        self.play(
            self.get_zoomed_display_pop_out_animation(),
            unfold_camera,
            # -------> Inverse
            rate_func=lambda t: smooth(1-t),
        )
        self.play(
            Uncreate(zoomed_display_frame),
            FadeOut(frame),
        )
        self.wait()
```

When I render this with Manim, I find that the zooming does not work as I expected. Here is a screenshot from the video:

[image]

When not zoomed in, the line is quite thick. But in the zoomed in display, the line appears significantly thinner. Why is this? Can I fix this effect, so that line thickness scales properly with zoom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
        # Set camera
        zoomed_camera = self.zoomed_camera
        zoomed_camera.cairo_line_width_multiple = 0.1 # <-
```

The thickness is calculated in [this way](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/48f2a1ec3c86f3ad26b6b1292b6917149005cbab/manimlib/camera/camera.py#L393).